# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning when an array is empty Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, promise, try-catch

In the following code obj1 and obj2 are arrays.

```
if(obj2.length != 0) {
    func(obj1, obj2);
}
//execute func only when obj2 is not empty
```

var func = (obj1, obj2) => {

```
const Channel = obj2.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
    obj1.forEach((item) => {
        if (curVal.Channel.includes('Name')) {
            item.dataarr.push({ 'MobileNo': curVal.mobnum})
        }
    })
    return obj1;
}, [])
```

};

But when `obj2` is empty I get this error :

```
(node:10837) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: obj2.reduce is not a function
    at func (/home/user/Desktop/serv.js:708:37)
    at breakdata (/home/user/Desktop/serv.js:720:5)
    at cached.getMulti.then (/home/user/Desktop/serv.js:643:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:10837) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10837) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Ignore these line from the error above :

```
 at breakdata (/home/user/Desktop/serv.js:720:5)
 at cached.getMulti.then (/home/user/Desktop/serv.js:643:7)\
```

as they are thrown because obj2.reduce doesn't give any output when the exception is thrown.

How do I handle :  `obj2.reduce is not a function` when obj2 array is empty? I don't want this code to throw exceptions as the log file generated is huge.
I'm not getting how to add a catch block here. How do I do this?

Comment: `obj2.reduce is not a function` means `obj2` is not an empty array but not an array at all. Every array, empty or not, has `.reduce`.

Comment: Oh I get it. So instead of if(obj2.length != 0) should I add a condition to check if obj2 is an array or not right?

Comment: Well, ideally you'd make sure that `obj2` is always an array. Ideally, `func` can rely on the second param being an array, and whatever is passed is checked beforehand.

Comment: how do I check if obj2 is array or not? I checked solutions but getting confused

Comment: Array.isArray(obj2) is this correct?

Comment: @ChrisG your suggestion to check if obj2 is an array or not worked for me

Comment: Great! You can also try this: `var func = (obj1 = [], obj2)` this will assign an empty array to  `obj1` if it is undefined or null.